# error procssing gravityRequest in tomcat 7

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat7, flex4, graniteds

I configured a java/flex web app using granite ds.
the gravity servlet is configured well in web.xml .

when the gravity request hits the server I have this error (log message in tomcat) :

```
500 returned for /Migration/gravityamf/amf with message org.apache.catalina.CometProcessor
```

and the cause was :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.CometProcessor
```

does this error means some path i can dig into it.

Answer (score 1):

That application has been written for Tomcat 6 and won't run on Tomcat 7 without being modified to use the new package for the Comet classes.

Comment: that's right . Tomcat 7 has native support for asynchronous requests and the new protocol is enabled by default.